# Menu items in moodle

Tags: moodle

I am new to moodle. I created a moodle site in that I create custom menuitems. After clicking on theose menu items for example I created menu items like Home, Aboutus, when i click on Aboutus menu item it shows aboutus details in my site where and how to create that aboutus page in moodle.

thanking you

Comment: Need a bit more detail really - how have you created the menus?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to create a page on a Moodle site is to use the 'page' resource type.

If you edit the 'front page' settings and tick the 'include a topic section' option (and click save changes!).

Then, back on the front page, turn editing on, click on 'Add an activity or resource' and create a new 'Page' resource.

Once you've created that page resource, you can then copy the link for that page (from the front page) and use that as the 'about us' link.

Answer (score 0):

For example if you want to create a new page with a title "New page" and a header "External" you can create a new php file `external.php` or whatever and put the following code in it:

```
<?php

// file external.php is the the root directory of Moodle
require_once('config.php');

// Open the page if the user is logged in
if (isloggedin()) {
    $PAGE->set_context(get_system_context());
    $PAGE->set_pagelayout('standart');
    $PAGE->set_title("New page");
    $PAGE->set_heading("External");

    // path to this file
    $PAGE->set_url($CFG->wwwroot . '/external.php');

    // Code for navigation bar (Home -> Important)
    $PAGE->navbar->ignore_active();
    $strHome = "important";
    $PAGE->navbar->add($strHome, new moodle_url('external.php'));

    // Output the header
    echo $OUTPUT->header();
    $htmlscr = "<h1>Hello world!</h2>";

    // Actual content goes here
    echo $htmlscr;
    echo $jscr;
    echo $OUTPUT->footer();
}
// Else output error message
else {
    echo "<h2>Please log in to procede</h2>";
}
?>
```

This page can be seen by logged in users only. It works fine in my Moodle 2.6.
More details are in the Moodle documentation https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Page_API